# How can I import component-specific css styles in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

This is the structure that I'm trying to mimic (from [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate)):

```
component
  |Footer
    |style.css
    |Footer.js
```

Inside Footer.js the styles are imported quite elegantly this way:

```
import React from 'react';
import A from 'components/A';

import styles from './styles.css';

function Footer() {
  return (
    <footer className={styles.footer}>
      <section>
        <p>This project is licensed under the MIT license.</p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <p>Made with love by <A href="https://twitter.com/mxstbr">Max Stoiber</A>.</p>
      </section>
    </footer>
  );
}

export default Footer;
```

className(s) are then generated for the footer element to apply the style to that specific component.

But when I try to mimic this structure in my project it's not working. The imported `styles` object is always empty. I suspect I might be lacking some dependency but I can't figure out what it might be.

I would like to know which dependency I might be lacking and/or webpack configuration I need to do in order to apply the same structure to my project.

Comment: you are trying to import styles from './styles.css' but you need import from style.css

Comment: Verify the import path and ensure that you have a configured a [CSS loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) in your webpack config

Comment: That pattern is from CSS Modules, see here for more info: https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may config your webpack like this

```
. . .
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]' 
}
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite not sure about it, but it seems you are looking for `styles.css` with `javascript
import styles from './styles.css';`
 
and you have a `style.css`in your directory :)